# How to fix 'Controller's length property does not match the number of tabs present in TabBar's tabs property.'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm generating a `NestedScrollView` comprised of an AppBar + TabBar + TabBarView with a dynamic number of tabs depending on values I have stored in the app's state.

When the number of tabs to be generated is greater than 1, an error is thrown with the following message:
`Controller's length property (<actual tab length>) does not match the number of tabs (1) present in TabBar's tabs property.`

For some reason it seems that the TabBar's `tabs` length is always 1 although the same variable is used to determine the length everywhere in the code.

What am I missing here?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_app/models/app_state_container.dart';
import 'package:test_app/utils/seeder.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:test_app/views/tabs/home/team_row.dart';

class MyLeaderboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyLeaderboardState createState() => _MyLeaderboardState();
}

class _MyLeaderboardState extends State<MyLeaderboard> {
  final _tabName = "Leaderboard";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var container = AppStateContainer.of(context);
    var appState = container.state;

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: appState.leaderboard.groups.length,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(_tabName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    appState.leaderboard = Seeder.generateLeaderboard();
                  }),
                ),
              ],
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              snap: true,
              forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: appState.leaderboard.groups.map((g) => Text(g.name)).toList(),
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              slivers: appState.leaderboard.groups
                  .map((g) => SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) {
                          final int itemIndex = index ~/ 2;
                          if (index.isEven) {
                            return TeamRow(g.teams[itemIndex]);
                          }
                          return Divider(
                            height: 1,
                          );
                        },
                        childCount: max(0, g.teams.length * 2 - 1),
                      )))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was not building the body of the `TabBarView` properly, (I was doing multiple `SliverList`s inside  a `CustomScrollView` instead of multiple `CustomScrollView`s.

Here is the working `build` method of the code posted in my question:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var container = AppStateContainer.of(context);
    var appState = container.state;

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: appState.leaderboard.groups.length,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(_tabName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    appState.leaderboard = Seeder.generateLeaderboard();
                  }),
                ),
              ],
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              snap: true,
              forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: appState.leaderboard.groups
                    .map((g) => Text(g.name))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: appState.leaderboard.groups
              .map((g) => CustomScrollView(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (context, index) {
                            final int itemIndex = index ~/ 2;
                            if (index.isEven) {
                              return TeamRow(g.teams[itemIndex]);
                            }
                            return Divider(
                              height: 1,
                            );
                          },
                          childCount: max(0, g.teams.length * 2 - 1),
                        ))
                      ]))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first time I had this error, the code was like this:

`child: TabBarView(children: [],controller: _tabController,)`

Then the amendment was done and the contents were given as follows:
That I Have Three Tabs

```
child: TabBarView(children: [
      Container( ),
      Container( ),
      Container( ),
    ],controller: _tabController,)
```

And then the code worked systematically